# Spark: Remove Content-Type header

Tags: java, spark-framework

I'm trying to remove the Content-Type header in spark. It seems to be impossible as when I try to set it to `null` using the `type` or `header` methods. It just defaults to `text/html`.

Comment: If you try to disable it for a static file, you can disable the mime type Guessing before starting the server with: `Service.ignite().staticFiles.disableMimeTypeGuessing();`

Comment: I want to do it for regular routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the Content-Type value in the header, set the response type with an empty String `response.type("")`.

Here, an example of code that works on Spark v2.6.0:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", new Route() {
            @Override
            public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
                response.type("");
                response.body("hello world");
                return response;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Httpie command output (`http 0.0.0.0:4567/hello`):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 14 Aug 2017 19:12:17 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.4.4.v20170414)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

spark.Response@592d7509
```

Comment: At least with Spark 2.8.0, this doesn't work. The Content-Type header is just set to empty string.

`> curl -i "http://localhost:4567/hello"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Sep 2018 15:19:19 GMT
Content-Type:
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)

spark.Response@18dfe89f`